# MongoDB select documents based on multiple fields

Tags: mongoid, mongodb-query, mongoid4

Let's say we have the following documents in a collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55aa9d35dccf57b64d34f448"),
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 7,
    "c" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55aa9d64dccf57b64d34f449"),
    "a" : 2,
    "b" : 8,
    "c" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55aa9d6bdccf57b64d34f44a"),
    "a" : 2,
    "b" : 7,
    "c" : 0
}
```

I want to get all documents where `(a = 1 and b = 7) or (a = 2 and b = 8)`. The query will always be only on fields `a` and `b`, but there are going to be maybe ten thousand of possible `a` and `b` pairs (combinations).

Is there a way to do this kind of a query using `$in` operator?

If not, what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying MongoDB query you're trying to build is:

```
$or: [
    { a: 1, b: 7 },
    { a: 2, b: 8 }
]
```

That translates directly to:

```
Model.where(:$or => [
    { :a => 1, :b => 7 },
    { :a => 2, :b => 8 }
])
```

or you could use the `or` method:

```
Model.or(
    { :a => 1, :b => 7 },
    { :a => 2, :b => 8 }
)
```

You don't need `$in` here, you'd use `$in` to see if a single field is equal to any of an array's elements. For example, these are equivalent:

```
where(:$or => [ { :a => 1 }, { :a => 2 } ])
where(:a => { :$in => [ 1, 2 ] })
where(:a.in => [ 1, 2 ]) # a short form of :a => { :$in => ... }
```

So `$in` is a special case shortcut for certain `$or`s.